# Is it possible to set a linebreak in l columns

Tags: tables

Im using tabu to span tables over the full width, but I would like to span only the first column (i.e. the space between first and second column) and let TeX use the natural width of the other columns. To do that I define the first as `X` and the others as `l`or `r`. But in most of the cases the table head is much longer than the column’s content (some numbers) so it would be great if I could define some line breaks in the head without using `p{}` and guess the right column width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu,booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabh}{\bfseries\raggedright}

\begin{document}
Working but not exactly what I want:

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[l,2]X[r,2]X[r,1]}
    \toprule
    \tabh Land &
        \tabh Zahl der Plätze in der\linebreak Jugendpsychiatrie &
        \tabh Jugendliche\linebreak unter 18 \\
    \midrule
    Schleswig-Holstein & 216 & 501\,667 \\
    Hamburg & 110 & 271\,75 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\bigskip%
What I want but not working:

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {Xrr}
    \toprule
    \tabh Land &
        \tabh Zahl der Plätze in der\linebreak Jugendpsychiatrie &
        \tabh Jugendliche\linebreak unter 18 \\
    \midrule
    Schleswig-Holstein & 216 & 501\,667 \\
    Hamburg & 110 & 271\,75 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I usually just split it in two lines in the table, that is: `header & header two & header three` would become `header & header & header\\ & two & three`. How well this works really depends on the alignment of the columns though.

Comment: @wh1t3: Damn … thats so easy, I didn’t think on that. If you post this as an answer I can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply split the header in two separate lines in the table, in fact creating two rows.

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {Xrr}
    \toprule
    \tabh Land &
        \tabh Zahl der Plätze in der &
        \tabh Jugendliche\\
        & \tabh Jugendpsychiatrie & \tabh unter 18 \\
    \midrule
    Schleswig-Holstein & 216 & 501\,667 \\
    Hamburg & 110 & 271\,75 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
```

Resulting in the following table:

[image: Table with split headers]

Comment: Thanks again. I changed the definition of `\tabh` to `\newcommand{\tabh}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries#1}}` to get left aligned heads and flushright columns. But this works only with `tabularx` instead of `tabu` because `tabu` has some problems with `\multicol`

Comment: @Tobi: Yeah, it has issues with `multirow` as well, which would allow for an alternative way to solve it.